# dagger2 non-@Nullable @Provides method

Tags: android, firebase, dependency-injection, dagger-2

I'm at the beginning of use Dagger to my projects. 
I've made this modules:

```
@Module
public class FirebaseModule {

@Provides @Singleton
public FirebaseUser provideCurrentUser(){
    return FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
}

@Provides @Singleton
public DatabaseReference provideDatabaseReference(){
    return FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
}

@Provides @Singleton
public FirebaseAuth provideFirebaseAuth(){
    return FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
}
}
```

and this:

```
@Module
public class AppModule
{
private HappyParkApp app;

public AppModule(HappyParkApp app) {
    this.app = app;
}

@Provides
public HappyParkApp providesApp()
{
return this.app;
}

@Provides
public Context getAppContext(){
    return this.app;
}
}
```

I've also made the component:

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = {AppModule.class,
                      FirebaseModule.class})
public interface AppComponent {

    void inject(MainActivity activity);
}
```

and this is the appComponent implemented in the application:

```
public class HappyParkApp extends Application {

private AppComponent appComponent;
private static HappyParkApp instance = new HappyParkApp();
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    createAppComponent();
}

public static HappyParkApp getInstance() {
    return instance;
}

public AppComponent createAppComponent() {
 if(appComponent == null){
     appComponent = DaggerAppComponent.builder()
             .appModule(new AppModule(this))
             .firebaseModule(new FirebaseModule()).build();
 }

 return appComponent;
}
```

}

so I've tried to to this in `onCreate()` method of MainActivity:

```
HappyParkApp.getInstance().createAppComponent().inject(this);
```

and this before:

```
 @Inject
FirebaseUser user;

@Inject
DatabaseReference reference;

@Inject
FirebaseAuth mAuth;
```

but I'm getting this error:

```
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot return null from a non-@Nullable @Provides method
```

at this line:

```
 HappyParkApp.getInstance().createAppComponent().inject(this);
```

and I don't know how to fix it: what is the error? Is this a wrong injection?

Thank you

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> Cannot return null from a non-@Nullable @Provides method

You try to provide `null` from a provider method that is *not* marked as `@Nullable`.

Have a look at [getCurrentUser()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseAuth.html#getCurrentUser())

> Returns the currently signed-in FirebaseUser or null if there is none.

So in case there is no signed in user, this will be `null`, making the following invalid...

```
@Provides @Singleton
public FirebaseUser provideCurrentUser(){
  return FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser(); // could be null!
}
```

So to fix it you have 2 options:

- provide `FirebaseAuth` and grab the user in your application code, or
- mark the provider as `@Nullable`

Which approach is better depends on your setup, but since you put the user in a `@Singleton` scoped component I recommend *not* providing the user, as it is likely to change within the lifetime of "Singleton".

Either move it into a different Scope (e.g. `@UserScope` or `@PerUser`) or just grab the user where you need it using `FirebaseAuth.getCurrentUser()`. You can ofc still provide `FirebaseAuth`.

Also [read about nullability here](https://google.github.io/dagger/api/latest/dagger/Provides.html).

Comment: thank you, you helped me to understand this concept ;)

Comment: I marked method that could provide null value as @Nullable as well as places where I am providing this value, but anyway I get such error `...is not nullable, but is being provided by @Provides @android.support.annotation.Nullable` . What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6):

if you annotate your provider method with @Nullable and forget to use @Nullable whenever you want to use that object dagger will throw an error (`is not nullable but is being provided by @Provides @android.support.annotation.Nullable`)

so simply use if you provide a nullable object make sure to add @Nullable to every method that uses that object as a parameter

ex:

```
@Nullable
@Provides
static Object provideHomePost(MainActivity activity){
    return activity.getObject();
}
@Provides
static Presenter providePresenterFactory(@Nullable HomePost post) {
    return new CommentPresenterImpl(post);
}
```

Comment: Great answer, thanks. In my case I forgot to annotate the actual object being injected with `@Inject @Nullable User user`